# how to python win32com use eml file open outlook. attachment file extract and body content read

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, win32com, outlook.application

python `win32com` use open `Outlook.Application`. **eml** attachment files extract. and read subject and body content. use python native package use. eml file format.

**Code**

```py
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem("C:\\sample\\todo.eml")

print(msg)
```

**error**

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "init.py", line 4, in <module>
    msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem("C:\\sample\\todo.eml")
  File "<COMObject GetNamespace>", line 2, in OpenSharedItem
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 
'Microsoft Outlook', 'Invalid path or URL.', None, 0, -2147352567), None)
```

python use eml file open win32com module to use.
**any ideas to share**

Answer (score 0):

It can be for two reasons:
1.- The command: *" outlook.OpenSharedItem[...]"* cannot be executed in the console as before, even if you use "cmd", this same line will give you the same error.
2.- You do not have Outlok installed on your PC (which is necessary to execute this type of command)